# What do these negative volumes on the price chart denote?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-analysis

I keep on seeing these negative volume values on my price chart. In the example below it's showing volume as -2.04 M.

As I understand volume, it denotes the total number of shares or any other instrument that has changed hands. How can that be negative?

PS: The image below is from https://in.investing.com/equities/interglobe-aviation-ltd-chart

[image: Indigo]

Comment: bad data, maybe?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your link explains the likely reason:

> Disclaimer: Fusion Media would like to remind you that the data contained in this website is not necessarily real-time nor accurate. All CFDs (stocks, indexes, futures), cryptocurrencies, and Forex prices are not provided by exchanges but rather by market makers, and so prices may not be accurate and may differ from the actual market price, meaning prices are indicative and not appropriate for trading purposes. Therefore Fusion Media doesn't bear any responsibility for any trading losses you might incur as a result of using this data.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, it's speculation.